# How to get roles in an azure ad multi-tenant dotnet web app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid

I've set up a multi-tenant authentication web app that goes through the /common issuer using openid. I am able to sign in from the different tenants. However, the user roles claims are not being sent in the id token when authenticating this way.

I've used 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps as the primary references to complete this, but after attempting to follow all the steps, the roles still do not show up.

If I switch the application to use single tenant, and use the tenant specific issuer, the roles do show up in the claim token as I'd expect, so I don't believe it is a configuration problem when setting up the roles. How do I get the roles to show up when using /common or is there a different approach needed entirely to access the roles when doing a multitenant application?

Answer (score 0):

i assume you set up the app roles in the manifest and assigned the user to one of the app roles you put in manifest? and tested with that user? 
because it is supposed to work. 
have a read here: pretty good write-up about it.
https://goodworkaround.com/2019/12/06/building-a-multi-tenant-azure-ad-application-with-roles/

Comment: Yes, we set up roles in the manifest and were able to assign them to users in the azure portal. This link is also one we used when trying to set it up, but for some reason the role claims are still missing, even though they are assigned in azure

Comment: I just tried the example in the link i sent above, and if you follow the instructions, after adding the user to a color role, if you run the same authentication process again get the code and user powershell to get the id token, the role Does show up correctly in the token. i tried it for 2 different tenants logging in along with original tenant. Did you check the token to confirm the roles are in the token itself using that powershell bit?